# How to get the last two rows

Tags: teradata

The table is 
 I need to get the last two event associates for each event

```
event_id    event_date  event_associate
1           2/14/2014   ben
1           2/15/2014   ben
1           2/16/2014   steve
1           2/17/2014   steve   // this associate is the last but one for event 1
1           2/18/2014   paul    // this associate is the last  for event 1
2           2/19/2014   paul
2           2/20/2014   paul    // this associate is the last but one for event 2 
2           2/21/2014   ben     // this associate is the last  for event 2
3           2/22/2014   paul
3           2/23/2014   paul
3           2/24/2014   ben
3           2/25/2014   steve   // this associate is the last but one for event 3
3           2/26/2014   ben     // this associate is the last for event 3
```

I need to find out who was the last but one **event_associate** for each event . The result should be

```
  event_id      event_associate      rn
    1             steve             2
    1             paul              1
    2             paul              2
    2             ben               1
    3             steve             2
    3             ben               1
```

I tried

```
SELECT t.* , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY event_associate ORDER BY event_date DESC) rn 
FROM mytable t
QUALIFY rn < 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"for each event"** -> PARTITION BY event_id

**"last but one"** -> ORDER BY event_date DESC

Answer (score 1):

you have to count the number of row in your data base and then use this query

```
        sql=sql+" LIMIT "+NumberOfRowsToShowInTables+" OFFSET "+(countrow-         NumberOfRowsToShowInTables);
```

where   `countrow` is he number of row in your database

`NumberOfRowsToShowInTables` equal 2 as you mentioned 
sql is your normal query without limitation

Comment: 1st: This is supposed to be Teradata SQL, but there's no LIMIT/OFFSET in TD. 2nd: Even if this was valid SQL it would not return a row for **each event**